# How can the compiler reference its own output

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-construction

"foreach" is a keyword of Java language and when compiler encounters this keyword in the source, it knows that the collection following this keyword must implement "iterable" interface. 
The "iterable" interface itself is a piece of compiled Java code so how can the compiler reference its own output, how can the compiler be dependent on its own output?

Think of a hypothetical point in past time when there is only Java compiler (probably written with C or C++) and Java framework is not compiled yet. Java.lang package and all the stuff in it is not compiled yet so there is no Iterable interface at that moment in time. The Java compiler will compile the source code for Java.lang package from source code and build the bytecode for iterable interface in the future. At that point in time somehow Java compiler has to know about the iterable interface (since it is part of the language specification) so it can compile source code that uses foreach iterator. How is this made possible?

Comment: The simplest way to think about this is that 'linking' in Java happens at runtime. Also compiled java code (bytecode) is standardized and introspectable as you can see by invoking, say, javap.

Comment: for a start "foreach" is not a keyword. Can't you say the same about a variable assignment or anything that the compiler does?

Comment: The `String` class is also a Java class, and the `Class` class. Why should there be a problem with that?

Comment: To get better answers consider clarifying what you mean by "how can the compiler *reference its own output*, how can the compiler *be dependent on its own output*".

Comment: Even with your edit, it's not really clear what you're asking. It seems to be some sort of question about bootstrapping a compiler, perhaps you can come up with the simplest possible version of it? The whole business with 'foreach', etc seems superfluous and confusing, beside the fact that neither foreach nor Iterable were around when the Java compiler was being bootstrapped.

Comment: @pvg, my point exactly. foreach statement is just an example for this, there are many more. My question is: The iterable interface itself is compiled by the Java compiler yet it is part of the language specification which the compiler is built based on. How can the compiler be dependent on its own output?

Comment: I still don't understand this. The `lang` package is part of the language spec. This has some implications but it's not clear how what you're asking is different from 'how does the compiler resolve anything'. Maybe you can rephrase your question in terms of, dunno, `String` or something.

Comment: Perhaps the relation between Java compiler and Java.lang package will lead me to the answer, IDK. Let me put it this way: In order to create a hypothetical programming language you need to write down its language specs, then build the compiler that meets those specs and compile source code that is written according to those specs. I presume Java.lang package is one such piece of code that is compiled using the Java compiler. Now, how can we build a complete Java compiler (that meets the language specs) when some of the things in its language specs need to be built by the compiler?

Comment: There's nothing magical about being in the spec. There is special cased behavoirs in some places - for instance, your compiler has to know what literals are. But lets say you write the emre package and then declare emre is part of the emreJava spec. What's the problem?

Comment: Doesn't the compiler need to get its hands on the compiled bytecode of iterable interface in order to compile other source code that uses foreach statements?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189816/discussion-between-e-mre-and-pvg).

Comment: Sure. But the compiler gets its hands on the compiled code (or compiles the source first) whenever it encounters some new class and the compiler has to know that certain constructs imply certain types. To compile "foo ".trim() the compiler has to find `String`. Is that equivalent to what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

First of all , "`foreach`" is not a java keyword. Search for "`extended for loop in java`". 
The second thing , Interfaces in java are just to abstract the real implementation. This is not must to implement Interface when we have the real Implemention Class. But, to follow the good design principles like SOLID principles, we make Interfaces to abstract real implementations first, and also for multiple class hierarchies in java. 
Keywords do not implement Interfaces.If java keyword implement and refer any java code then its definitely related to bootstrapping means Java Compiler Written in Java Language. Overall answer to your long question is you need to Study about Compiler Construction, Building JVM Language, Bootstrapping etc.